# Values of p and q when e = 3 (RSA)?

Tags: rsa, algorithm-design

I am doing a paper on textbook RSA (this is for high school btw) and in my example I need two very large primes, but I want my $e = 3$.

Is there a short way to calculate the values of $p$ and $q$ such that $gcd(e, φ(pq)) = 1$?

Comment: Sample primes at random until you find two (p, q) such that 3 divides neither (p-1) nor (q-1).

Comment: Do you need to know how to find large primes, or just how to find large primes with that property?

Comment: puzzlepalace's hint can be rewritten as "test only numbers that are 2 mod 3 for primeness".